# DIfference between aggregation using executeCommand and spring data mongo aggregation api?

Tags: aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to understand what is difference between the following code when both does the aggregation. Which approach is better?

```
//Code1:
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("aggregate", "inputData");
BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("amtAllowed", new BasicDBObject("$ne", 0));
pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$match", filter));
List<BasicDBObject> results = (List<BasicDBObject>) 
mongoOperations.executeCommand(String.valueOf(query)).get("result");


//Code 2:
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("amtAllowed").ne(0)));
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "inputData", Document.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

`MOngoTemplate.aggregate()` - internally uses `mongoOprations.executeCommand()`